# How can I bind F3 behavior on key 5 on numeric keypad in midnight commander?

Tags: mc

How can I bind <kbd>F3</kbd> behavior on key 5 on the numeric keypad in Midnight Commander?

It will be very usable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rebind keys in Midnight Commander. But you can use alternate keys. If <kbd>F3</kbd> doesn't work for you, press <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>.

Try the command <kbd>F9</kbd> → *Options* → *Learn keys...*. It allows to adapt Midnight Commander to the terminal.